# AngularJS custom directive loosing root properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have created a sidebar custom directive. It's working properly as it loads on where it should. What isn't working properly are the  tags. Their supposed behavior is that of a drowpdown, where when clicked they show their inner elements. It works properly when the  code is pasted directly but not when the directive is called with the code inside the other html file. I took 2 screenshots to show the difference between using a class="page-sidebar" inside the file that contains the html code of the directive and using it on the "root" file:

[image: inside the directive]

[image: outside]

It's pretty clear that several properties on the highlighted lines are not being applied on the first one.

Please help as I need this as a "partial" view to be used across several pages.

EDIT: Directive code:

```
app.directive('sidebar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "/app/views/sidebar.html"
    };
});
```

EDIT2:

Adding this in the post because it might be confusing from how I explained it:

I see where the confusion might be but they're different things. < sidebar > is a directive created by me. class="page-sidebar" is from the template I'm using and is what formats everything to its place. I tried to insert the class="page-sidebar" into the directive to see if it would work, but they're different things.

EDIT3:

To clear up the confusion, I hope: both pics show the sidebar is working. I know it's an element and as such I'm using < sidebar >, it's working, this is not the problem. The problem is when I use it, the contents such as Dropdowns (as shown in the second pic) don't work when I click them, while when the element contents are simply pasted into the index.html and not in the sidebar.html, it works.

[image]

[image]

EDIT4:

Found the issue but still no solution. I changed some stuff up and instead of the sidebar it's now on the widgets. Sidebar is now always loaded and it's the page contents which are loaded depending on the URL. This helped me track down the issue:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({mouseDrag: false, touchDrag: true, slideSpeed: 300, paginationSpeed: 400, singleItem: true, navigation: false,autoPlay: true});
```

The previous code is in a plugins.js file which is included in the html. For some reason, this line is NOT being run when the page is loaded. When I ran this line in the chrome console, the proper widget appeared.

For some reason, the js contents are not being run when the page loads.

Comment: Could you post some of your directive code? It is probably something on the directive...

Comment: Edited it in the original post!

Comment: use `restrict = 'C'` and if you are using `restrict: 'E'  then use element tag i.e `<sidebar>`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the `restrict: 'E',`, which is restricting it to elements. This explains why it works for `<sidebar>`, but not for `<div class="sidebar">`. If you want to use classes, you need to change it to `restrict: 'C'`.

Another problem is that when you are trying to use the directive as a class, you are using `class="page-sidebar"` rather than `class="sidebar"`.

See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for directives.

Comment: @Forget - updated the answer... you want `restrict: 'C'` if you want your directive to only apply to classes.

Comment: I see where the confusion might be but they're different things. <sidebar> is a directive created by me. class="page-sidebar" is from the template I'm using and is what formats everything to its place. I tried to insert the class="page-sidebar" into the directive to see if it would work, but they're different things!

Answer (score 0):

From angular documentation:

The restrict option is typically set to:

- 'A' - only matches attribute name
- 'E' - only matches element name
- 'C' - only matches class name
- 'M' - only matches comment
  These restrictions can all be combined as needed:

'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name

Comment: please check EDIT3. I understood everyone's having the same confusion and I don't believe that is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The directive definition object for your `sidebar` quite clearly states that it will treat a DOM node with the tag name `sidebar` to render the directive template due to the `restrict : 'E'` property.

So use the directive as an HTML node, and NOT in a class (as it would require the property `restrict` to be set to `C` letter).

```
<sidebar></sidebar>
```

Comment: I edited it in the OP, but here's what's happening: The sidebar element was created by me. It's working properly, it's done. The page-sidebar is a class created by the admin template page I'm using. It's because of the css and all that. The problem is when the contents of sidebar.html are inside the index, it works properly, however, when I move the contents to sidebar.html and simply use de < sidebar > element, it shows the proper ul and li and stuff BUT the dropdowns, for example, don't work. Hope I could clear it up!

Comment: @Forget, I suppose that the dropdowns might not be working because they cannot access the functions from the parent scope.
Can you add your angular code that is involved in the whole scenario, i.e. the _controller_ or whatever that has the logic for the dropdown buttons. Meanwhile, I need to take a look at the `/app/views/sidebar.html` structure.

Comment: Check my edit please. I changed the structure as now the sidebar is "fixed" and the page content is loaded depending on the URL. I have some widgets there from the template which worked before but don't work now. Any questions that can help please do state!

Comment: You said that _The previous code is in a plugins.js file which is included in the html._, do you mean that you are loading Javascript ___in___ the HTML template for your `sidebar` directive?

Comment: The sidebar directive is no more! I use a ui-view, something I saw that is quite useful. These are my "important" files: index.html that has the html code for the sidebar AND the ui-view which allows me to inject code where it is. In this case I inject the contents from dashboard.html which has several widgets in them. So these widgets work I have a script with src="js/plugins.js" which has the code I said in the latest edit. The expected behavior is to run whatever is in that plugins.js file but it doesn't :/